# Use Fragments (ActionTabs) and Webview

Tags: java, android, android-activity, syntax-error

I want to have my app so that you have tabs at the top of the screen (got this working) and in the xml file you have a webview. I cannot get the webview and the fragment code to work as I get 'Unreachable Statement'.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class TopRatedFragment extends Activity {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);
        return rootView;

        //Unreachable Statement
        WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
        engine.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");

    }

}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: why web view need activity? can you explain why you need fragment and activity ? you can use `rootView.findViewById`

Comment: Sorry I did not post the question properly, please revisit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use following code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);

    WebView engine = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.web_engine); // `web_engine` must be in `fragment_top_rated`
    engine.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
    return rootView;
  }
}
```

Comment: in fragment class findViewById is undefined, you must use `yourView.findViewById`

Answer (score 3):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);

        //Unreachable Statement
        WebView engine = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
        engine.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        return rootView;

}
```

Unreachable because you are writing the code after return statement

Comment: It still throws an error afterwards but Shayan Pourvatan's answer works

Answer (score 0):

You are getting unreachable statement means you are writing pieces of stuff after the ***return*** statement. Kindly have a look at your code above.

Put:

```
WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
engine.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
```

Above:

```
return rootView;
```